# Trying to uninstall wifi hardware on MBP 2019 16". Previous MBP models method of .kext removal not working, or I can't find the right kext to remove

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, catalina, driver, kernel-extensions

First post, after searching this site and others for answers. Hopefully someone here can help me and others reading this.
Please don't judge, I bet it's not normal that someone asks how to BREAK their wifi.

I work alone at a home office, on cognitively draining focus intense creative work.
I have tried all the productivity apps, site blockers, timers etc, and NOTHING exists that cannot ultimately be worked around with a few clicks, without leaving my chair.
I share the wifi signal with others in the household, so switching this off is not possible.

Years ago, on my previous MBP, I settled on a workaround.
Copy the IO80211Family.kext to a thumb drive, and put that in a physically different location (having to leave my desk/office and having a cumbersome process for reinstallation is the only really effective short circuit in the battle of willpower vs procrastination)
Then in Terminal in recovery mode delete that kext from System/Library/Extensions folder.
Later on, when internet is again required on that machine, fetch that thumb drive, and reinstall the kext using kextbeast or another kext installer app.

So far so good, until this month, I purchased a new MBP, (16"2019) running Catalina 10.15.6, and deleting those kexts just does not work to uninstall the wifi hardware.

I am looking for a situation in which I can do something that leaves the wifi status saying 'hardware not installed' or similar, and the only way to fix is to re-install it at my own leisure using a file or key of some sort stored remotely on a usb stick.

An extra step either in Catalina or on this MBP model, is that I need to disable SIP in recovery mode before reinstalling kext files, then run
sudo mount -uw /
in terminal in normal mode before being able to reinstal the kext files. But that's not so difficult, and I then reset the SIP to enable and a restart resets the sudo command above so all good there.

By the way, in addition to removing IO80211Family.kext
I have also tried to disable the wifi hardware by removing:
IO80211FamilyV2.kext
BCMWLANFirmware4355_Hashstore.kext (and the variants 4364 & 4377)
AppleBluetoothModule.kext (bluetooth continued to work)
IOBluetoothFamily.kext (bluetooth continued to work)

To no avail. Wifi has continued to work just fine.
(note: they are all re-installed again now)

I suppose there is a different driver process in Catalina, or in this hardware model, and I would love any help or suggestions about a different workaround that achieves the same end.

Thanks!

Comment: possibly I just need to be pointed in the right direction for the kext file that needs to be removed, due to some new kind of wifi hardware being used now?

Comment: As a possible alternative: have you looked into the built-in 'Screen Time'? It allows you to set limits (no internet between the hours of... maximum X hours /day). You'd have to use a non-admin account and a piece of paper with the root pw becomes the McGuffin of this story

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes, that and a myriad other things and different apps. The issue is that it's not so difficult to override, and I'd have to override it many times. I do require a connection for a full day when finalising a project, but then not at all for several days in a row while in the thick of the next project. So I would prefer to have a solution that was hardware based. It also feels more solid, and not at risk of losing the root p/w, arguably worse than losing the thumb drive with the kext files. But I very much enjoyed discovering what a McGuffin is, thankyou for that :)